# MP4 videos on firebase hosting load irregularly on Chrome

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I'm running a Nuxt based website (Universal Mode) on Firebase hosting at this URL:
https://kloud-website.firebaseapp.com

The central animation is changed by loading small 36 x 50 videos in the background, pulling the pixels from the animation frames, and using those values to color a 2D array of spheres created with three.js.

Although it works in several other environments (listed below) I can't get the videos to play reliably on Chrome.
For example, when visiting this video URL, https://kloud-website.firebaseapp.com/videos/Antenna.mp4
The video generally won't play on a first visit to this address (although it does if I refresh the page).
This seems to break the video change effect in the visuals.

However, it works reliably here, on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu, Apache 2 server:

http://kloud-dev.v0.run/ (Try clicking "contact" or "shows")

Also see http://kloud-dev.v0.run/videos/Antenna.mp4

It also works reliably when I serve the website locally (via firebase serve --only functions,hosting)
And it also runs from the Firebase URL on Firefox, but not Chrome:
https://kloud-website.firebaseapp.com

The video element is created dynamically as follows:

```
const vidRef = document.createElement('video')
const defaultAnimation = '/videos/Blinking.mp4'

function _initVideo () {
    vidRef.src = defaultAnimation
    vidRef.loop = false
    vidRef.muted = true
    vidRef.addEventListener('ended', vidFinished, false)
    vidRef.play()
}
_initVideo()
```

All of this seems to work fine on the initial page load.

Later, the video is updated as follows:

```
vidRef.src = `/videos/${currentVideo}.mp4`
vidRef.play()
```

Here, the video seems to play, but then ends immediately, breaking the visuals (although there are no errors)

One more note - I added a "test" command (you can type it in the text prompt on the site) that triggers the playback of a WebM video, and that seems to load fine.
It also seems to play without any issues here:
https://kloud-website.firebaseapp.com/videos/load_special.webm

In the end I may end up switching all the videos to WebM, checking for support, and falling back on MP4 if necessary, but would still be interested in any insight.

Thanks in advance for your time.

**UPDATE:**
I still don't know why this is happening, but ended up solving it by converting all of the videos to WebM. Then, in the code, where I'm swapping out videos on the fly, I'm doing a check for WebM support. If it isn't supported, I'm loading MP4 instead. I suspect this all has something to do with Chrome H264 support.